# Trim overflow text in css?

Tags: html, css, trim

Is it possible to trim the ending of the text?

INPUT

> this is an extremely very long text

RESULT

> this is an ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can try

> text-overflow:ellipsis;

http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Comment: Embrace simplicity :) +1

Comment: Need overflow: hidden too. Doesn't work by itself

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that is possible to achieve solely by CSS.

See my [Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHBL3/)

Key for achieving the effect is to use a combination of the following CSS-properties:

```
width: [x]px
overflow: hidden
white-space: nowrap
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

The width is neccessary to use overflow. Overflow is needed for text-overflow and white-space is needed to prevent breaks and to assure that the whole text is in one line.